# php update dateformat to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help me to update date to mySQL. My Add Item is functioning well and Add date to mySQL but when I try to Update, in mySQL the date appears "0000-00-00". Below are my code for update.

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if($_POST)
{
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
    $itemquantity = $_POST['itemquantity'];
    $itemdesc = $_POST['itemdesc'];
    $itemuom = $_POST['itemuom'];
    $reqdate = $_POST['reqdate'];
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($reqdate));
    try{
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE info SET itemno=$itemno, itemquantity=$itemquantity, itemdesc=$itemdesc, itemuom=$itemuom, reqdate=$newdate WHERE itemid=$itemid");
        $stmt->bindParam(":itemno", $itemno);
        $stmt->bindParam(":itemquantity", $itemquantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(":itemdesc", $itemdesc);
        $stmt->bindParam(":itemuom", $itemuom);
        $stmt->bindParam(":reqdate", $newdate);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "Successfully updated";
    }
    else{
        echo "Query Problem";
    }
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} ?>
```

I think I have problem in the updating query, Im not so much familiar with mysqli codes. Advance Thanks for the help

Comment: nope, that ain't prepared statements

Comment: plus, your tag is confusing, you tagged `mysqli` but using PDO methods

Comment: Your current code has SQL injections, which means anyone can read or destroy any data. Please read: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/660921)

Comment: change your code to a proper one shown in the linked answer and problem will disappear.